# What grep pattern allows to print only one-word lines?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

I want to print the lines with only one no-spaces subsequences of characters while use `grep` on the text.

`title` after grepping should to print `title`

`the sentence` after grepping should not print anything

Comment: This isn't really an Ubuntu specific question but try: `grep -E '^[A-Za-z]+$' filename` you might need fine tuning if you want to include numbers and symbols

Comment: ... or maybe easier to just exclude lines containing spaces like `grep -v ' ' filename` ... Will include other non-words though like `123456` for example.

Comment: @moo That looks like an answer! Btw we have plenty of highly-upvoted questions and answers on AskUbuntu about grep, sed, and other POSIX command line tools

Comment: Depending on your definition of "word", you might find this easier to do with awk ex. `awk 'NF==1' somefile`

Comment: @steeldriver Trying to escape RegEx :D … That will still print all numerical fields like `123456` which is certainly not a word by my definition … But, if you agree that something like `awk 'NF==1 && $0+0 != $0'` might remedy that and eliminate the need for RegEx, then you might want to add it as an answer.

Comment: `grep -E '^[^ ]+$' file`?

Answer (score 3):

To print lines containing only (and at least one) non-whitespace characters, use one of:

```
grep -x '[^[:space:]]\+'
grep -Ex '[^[:space:]]+'
```

Or with PCRE patterns:

```
grep -Px '\S+'
```

The [POSIX character class `\[:space:\]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html) matches:

> Space characters (these are: space, TAB, newline, carriage return, formfeed and vertical tab)

The `-x` option tells `grep` to select lines which completely match the pattern (as if you'd used `^\S+$`, for example).

Answer (score 2):

##### Without punctuation

```
grep -E '^\w*[[:alpha:]]\w*$' file
```

... that will only match  possible (zero or more `*`) word characters `\w` (alphabetical, numerical and underscore) that span the whole line `^...$` including  at least one strictly alphabetical character `[[:alpha:]]` ... The reason is to match words that have numbers and/or underscores in them like `1st_part`, `Title2` and `Loc8tor` ... etc. and exclude all numeric like `123456`.

##### With punctuation

To, also, include words that have punctuation like `Title.`, `Title:`, `Title,`, `(Title)`, `-title` and `long-title` ... etc. , add the relevant character class `[[:punct:]]` like this:

```
grep -E '^[[:punct:]]*\w*[[:punct:]]*[[:alpha:]]\w*[[:punct:]]*$' file
```

##### Notice

- All the above expressions should match characters from any locale (UNICODE included).
- The `-E, --extended-regexp` might not be needed for the above expressions, but is there in case you decide to expand them (which is expected).